# Query Times Worsen on 1 Server Vacuum/Analyze on Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql, query, postgresql-performance

We have a query which is called approx 15,000 times during the day. The query itself should take a few milliseconds to run.

I like to think we have the appropriate indexes in place for the query:

```
Server 1 


product=# explain analyze SELECT DISTINCT b.item_id FROM item.item b JOIN item.item_part bp USING (item_id) JOIN item.price p USING (price_id) WHERE selection_id = ANY ('{279099814,279099815,279099812,279099813}'::int[]) AND item_rejection_code_id IS NULL AND item_is_returned = FALSE AND item_is_resulted = FALSE; 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=1953583.43..1953583.62 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=226.287..226.287 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1953583.43..1953583.52 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=226.287..226.287 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: b.item_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.71..1953582.43 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=226.277..226.278 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.15..1948106.55 rows=1374 width=4) (actual time=71.269..219.473 rows=21 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using price_selection_id_idx on price p  (cost=0.58..4545.71 rows=5978 width=8) (actual time=1.431..171.302 rows=2464 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (selection_id = ANY ('{279099814,279099815,279099812,279099813}'::integer[]))
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_item_part_price_id on item_part bp  (cost=0.57..315.43 rows=969 width=12) (actual time=0.017..0.019 rows=0 loops=2464)
                           Index Cond: (price_id = p.price_id)
               ->  Index Scan using item_pkey on item b  (cost=0.56..3.98 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.322..0.322 rows=0 loops=21)
                     Index Cond: (item_id = bp.item_id)
                     Filter: ((item_rejection_code_id IS NULL) AND (NOT item_is_returned) AND (NOT item_is_resulted))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.715 ms
 Execution time: 226.348 ms
(16 rows)




Server 2 


product=# explain analyze SELECT DISTINCT b.item_id FROM item.item b JOIN item.item_part bp USING (item_id) JOIN item.price p USING (price_id) WHERE selection_id = ANY ('{279099814,279099815,279099812,279099813}'::int[]) AND item_rejection_code_id IS NULL AND item_is_returned = FALSE AND item_is_resulted = FALSE; 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=4278797.02..4278797.10 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=32459.594..32459.594 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4278797.02..4278797.06 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=32459.593..32459.593 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: b.item_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9952.49..4278796.73 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=32459.581..32459.581 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=9951.93..4275929.02 rows=733 width=4) (actual time=13991.276..32459.088 rows=74 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (bp.price_id = p.price_id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on item_part bp  (cost=0.00..3473000.28 rows=211458528 width=12) (actual time=0.047..17453.754 rows=211449508 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=9871.00..9871.00 rows=6474 width=8) (actual time=1.926..1.926 rows=1969 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 141kB
                           ->  Index Scan using price_selection_id_idx on price p  (cost=0.58..9871.00 rows=6474 width=8) (actual time=0.043..1.727 rows=1969 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (selection_id = ANY ('{279099814,279099815,279099812,279099813}'::integer[]))
               ->  Index Scan using item_pkey on item b  (cost=0.56..3.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=74)
                     Index Cond: (item_id = bp.item_id)
                     Filter: ((item_rejection_code_id IS NULL) AND (NOT item_is_returned) AND (NOT item_is_resulted))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 0.700 ms
 Execution time: 32459.684 ms
(18 rows)
```

When explain analyze the query can see one server differs massively from the other. Both environments have had a vaccum analyze run against the servers at near the same time. Yet we are seeing huge differences, predominantly on the Server 2 side where its doing a seq scan on item_part bp.

Why would Postgres behave in this manner?

There is an index idx_item_part_price_id which exists on Server 2 yet not being utilised.

I dont want to force PG to use sequential plans as I feel this will have a huge impact on other queries.

The servers are configured exactly the same in terms of memory and postgresql.conf settings.

Any help is much appreciated.

Update:

I have tried running the same query again but with `set enable_seqscan = off` in my session and see a dramatic improvement in the plan.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=4377530.62..4377530.70 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=7.913..7.913 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4377530.62..4377530.66 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=7.913..7.913 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: b.item_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.71..4377530.33 rows=15 width=4) (actual time=7.901..7.901 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.15..4374661.36 rows=733 width=4) (actual time=0.218..7.257 rows=74 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using price_selection_id_idx on price p  (cost=0.58..9900.05 rows=6493 width=8) (actual time=0.026..2.660 rows=1969 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (selection_id = ANY ('{279099814,279099815,279099812,279099813}'::integer[]))
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_item_part_price_id on item_part bp  (cost=0.57..668.32 rows=391 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1969)
                           Index Cond: (price_id = p.price_id)
               ->  Index Scan using item_pkey on item b  (cost=0.56..3.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=74)
                     Index Cond: (item_id = bp.item_id)
                     Filter: ((item_rejection_code_id IS NULL) AND (NOT item_is_returned) AND (NOT item_is_resulted))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 1.024 ms
 Execution time: 8.011 ms
(16 rows)
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: @jjanes updated the main body to include the query plan for the seqscan being off.

Answer (score 1):

The cost estimates of the fast and slow plans are pretty close together, so just random variation in the sampling method from ANALYZE to ANALYZE could push one over the other in an unpredictable fashion.  But that also means you don't need to get much of a change to push it back over to the actually fast one.

The misestimation is a compounding of several estimation problems.

The row count for the scan on price_selection_id_idx is misestimated by 3.3 fold (6493 to 1969).  This is not the most egregious problem, but is probably the easiest to fix.  Increase the sample size used for determining the stats on that column:

```
alter table item.price alter selection_id set statistics 1000;
```

And then ANALYZE and see if that improves things (of course I don't know what the current sample size is, but I am assuming you have not changed the default_statistics_target away from 100).  If that doesn't improve things, you could check if pg_stats.ndistinct is far off for that column.  But you might just want to change default_statistics_target itself, rather than changing if for individual columns, as there might be other misestimates out there too if that is set too low.

For the scan on idx_item_part_price_id, it costs it out as if each scan (of which it thinks there will be 6493) will find 391 rows, but each one actually finds less than one.  This is obviously a huge difference.  It could be because there are some values of price_id which are very common in item_part, just not the values you will actually be looking for.  It could also be compounded by bad stats due to an inadequate sample size, or bad estimate of ndistinct.  So, is it actually the case that some price_id are very popular?

Also, the cost estimate for finding those alleged 391 rows, 668.32, seems very high.  Part of this could be due to a too-low setting of effective_cache_size, so review that to make sure it is reasonable.  Also, if you `create index on item_part (price_id,item_id )` then it could use an index-only scan here.  That would actually be faster, but more important it would be *estimated* to be faster.

Why do you have so many rows in "price" which have no corresponding entry in "item_part"?  Why would a price exist, if it is not assigned to anything?  There may be legitimate reasons for that, but I think it needs some kind of explanation.

Comment: Sorry for such a delayed response. Ironically adding the index you suggested (create index on item_part (price_id,item_id )) made the world of difference, however I am puzzled as to why the index index idx_item_part_price_id does not get used. I will look into altering the statistics level I am just concerned the impact it would have on other queries. This is testing at the moment and such values are added in, How do I verify the statistics level change? I looked into the pg_attribute value but unsure how I would see it.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with the version of PostgreSQL running on both servers, and the DDL for the `item`, `item_part`, and `price` tables. You can use a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) if the definitions are large. Also, please explain the relationship between the servers -- physical replicas, logical replicas, copies made by backup & restore, etc.

Comparing your explain plans, it does not appear the databases have equivalent data. In the first plan, the inner join results in 21 rows while in the second plan 74 rows are returned. In both cases the outer nested loop disqualifies all the rows, resulting in 0 rows returned for the query.

You may want to re-run the query with the filters removed (`AND item_rejection_code_id IS NULL AND item_is_returned = FALSE AND item_is_resulted = FALSE`) and verify that the correct data is being returned. Differences in the source data will affect the statistics generated by `ANALYZE` and thus what plan is selected.

Comment: Thanks @dwhitemv, the confusing part for me the most was after vacuum/analyzing the query took a turn for the worse. They are separate servers but have the same code, understand the size of the data within the tables play a big part but after performing maintenance the query for Server 2 performs badly as added in the original message. It originally took around the same time as Server 1.